# Proof of energy-momentum tensor is zero in Polyakov action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The polyakov action is defined as

\begin{equation} 
S=-\frac{T}{2}\int d\sigma d\tau \sqrt{-h}h^{\alpha \beta} \partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu}\eta_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}

by varing this action with respect to metric yield:
\begin{equation}
T_{\alpha \beta}= \partial_{\alpha} X \cdot \partial_{\beta}X -\frac{1}{2}h_{\alpha \beta}h^{\gamma \delta}\partial_{\gamma}X \cdot \partial_{\delta}X 
\end{equation}

and by variation the action with respect to $X$ yield:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\alpha}(\sqrt{-h}h^{\alpha \beta}\partial_{\beta}X^{\mu})=0.
\end{equation}

It's mentioned in several literature that the equation of motion with respect to $h$ imply the energy-momentum tensor is zero, how this can be shown?

Comment: You can find it on page 23 in David Tong lectures on String Theory http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html

Comment: It can be shown explicitly by checking each indices, nonetheless, It's not imply from the equation of motion, a more appropriate derivation would be expanding the equation of motion that the functional form is equal or similar to the stress tensor, yet I am not able to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Varying the action with respect to $h^{\alpha \beta}$ yields
\begin{equation}
T_{\alpha \beta} = \partial_\alpha X \cdot \partial_\beta X - \frac{1}{2} h_{\alpha \beta} h^{\gamma \delta} \partial_\gamma X \cdot \partial_\delta X=0.
\end{equation}
Why did you include the "$=0$" in the equation from varying with respect to the $X^\mu$ fields but not in the one from varying with respect to $h^{\alpha \beta}$? The equations of motion are always found by setting to zero the variation of the action with respect to each of the fields, that includes the metric.